# ajax async working in browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I write a java script function in that i call Ajax to open window in same tab .when i am setting async:false it works in Mozilla but doesn't get work in chrome and IE.To work in Chrome and IE we need to set async:true but after setting async:true it doesn't work in Mozilla. 
  the following code i am using

example.

```
var t = document.getElementById('toolt').title = 'test';
t = 'test'
function loadEditWindow() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            success: function (MSG) {
                window.open('URL', "_self");
            }

            return false;


        },
        error: function (MSG) {
            alert("Error");
        }

        });
    }, 2000);
return false;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you have never to set an ajax request synchronous, this is deprecated

Comment: I believe in most modern browsers, `window.open` must be trigger by a user click, any other way of calling it will be blocked by the built-in popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

I tried cleaning up your code.

Try this:

```
function loadEditWindow() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            success: function (MSG) {
                window.open('URL', "_self");
            },
            error: function (MSG) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }, 2000);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your quick answer .but same issue occurs we cant navigate in chrome

Comment: @Swapnil Well, then what you asked in your original question is not the problem. I suggest closing this question, debug what is wrong and asking a new and informative one. "cant navigate in chrome" is not a good description.

Comment: sorry for my bad mistake.i tried Your provided code in application.but the same problem i am facing  .when i set Ajax async property to false  window.open(url) doesn't work in Google chrome and IE.the page is load itself and process is stopped